# padding with sprintf

Tags: c++, c, string, printf

I have a dummy question. I would like to print an integer into a buffer padding with 0 but I cannot sort it out the `sprintf`format.
I am trying the following

```
char buf[31];
int my_val = 324;
sprintf( buf, "%d030", my_val );
```

hoping to have the following string

```
"000000000000000000000000000324"
```

what am I doing wrong? It doesn't mean pad with 0 for a max width of 30 chars?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

`"%030d"` is the droid you are looking for

Comment: "The droids you are looking for are in the manual. They are called width and precision." :-)

Answer (score 14):

You got the syntax slightly wrong; The following code produces the desired output:

```
char buf[31];
int my_val = 324;
sprintf( buf, "%030d", (int)my_val );
```

From [Wikipedia's Article on Printf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf):

```
[...] printf("%2d", 3) results in " 3", while printf("%02d", 3) results in "03".
```

Comment: Why do you need to cast `my_val` to `int` when it's already an `int`?

Answer (score 7):

The padding and width come *before* the type specifier:

```
sprintf( buf, "%030d", my_val );
```

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
sprintf( buf, "%030d", my_val );
```

Comment: You probably already know this, but using `snprintf` style functions where you specify the buffer length is a good habit to get yourself in, as it helps prevent buffer overflows.

Answer (score 3):

Your precision and width parameters need to go between the '%' and the conversion specifier 'd', not after. In fact all flags do. So if you want a preceeding '+' for positive numbers, use '%+d'.

Answer (score 2):

It's `%030d`, with type-letter at the end.

Answer (score 1):

A fairly effective version that doesn't need any slow library calls:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void uint_tostr (unsigned int n, size_t buf_size, char dst[buf_size])
{
  const size_t str_size = buf_size-1;

  for(size_t i=0; i<str_size; i++)
  {
    size_t index = str_size - i - 1;
    dst[index] = n%10 + '0';
    n/=10;
  }
  dst[str_size] = '\0';
}


int main (void)
{
  unsigned int n = 1234;
  char str[6+1];
  uint_tostr(n, 6+1, str);
  puts(str);
}
```

This can be optimized further, though it is still probably some hundred times faster than `sprintf` as is.