# Padding specified number of zeros to a char array

Tags: c++

I want to pad a given char array to make it a 15 character array.

For eg. if the array contains two characters 1, 2 then 13 `0` characters should be padded to make in 000000000000012 and if contains five characters then 10 0s should be padded. The resultant array should contain 15 characters always.

Found one solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667183/padding-stl-strings-in-c) but that’s for stl string I need similar solution for char arrays. Please help.
What I have tried is below:

```
char moneyArray[256];
memset(moneyArray, 0, 256);    
for(int i=0;i<(15-strlen(moneyArray))-1;i++)
    sprintf(moneyArray,"0%s",moneyArray);
```

But I am looking for a standard solution if possible using a std function may be?

Comment: when you say padded with zeros, what *exactly* do you mean by *zeros*?

Comment: zeros mean characters `0` for e.g. `12` becomes `000000000000012`

Comment: OK, maybe specify that you mean `'0'`, not `0` in the question.

Comment: you can try with sprintf(); here's a thread on that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116994/padding-with-sprintf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're fine with `std::string` (and I think you should be), you can make use of its fill constructor:

```
char        s[]    = "12";
std::string padded = std::string( (15 - strlen(s) ), '0').append(s);
```

Of course you might want to check whether `strlen(s) > 15` first.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `pad` function below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

void pad(char *s, int n, int c) {
    char *p = s + n - strlen(s);
    strcpy(p, s);
    p--;
    while (p >= s) { p[0] = c; p--; }
}

int main () { 
    char b[16] = "123";
    pad(b, 15, '0');
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have various options; one of them would be (again under the assumption we already know that `moneyArray` contains a string and is a 16-byte buffer at least):

```
size_t len = strlen(moneyArray); 
memmove(moneyArray + 15 - len, moneyArray, len + 1);
memset(moneyArray, '0', 15 - len);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could just write code to move the chars up

```
char str[10] = "123456";
padStart(str, 7, '0');
```

`str` would become `"0123456"`. be sure the char array is large enough to fit the longer string

```
void padStart(char *str, int len, char padChar)
{
    // find the null terminator
    int strLen = 0;
    while (str[strLen] != '\0')
    {
        strLen++;
    };
    
    // is there anything to actually do
    if (strLen < len)
    {       
        // move the string up to the given length
        for (int i = 0; i <= strLen; i++) // notice the '<=' to include the \0 terminator
        {
            str[len - i] = str[strLen - i];
        }
        
        // add padChar to the start
        for (int i = 0; i < len - strLen; i++)
        {
            str[i] = padChar;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: quite complicated for a memmove and a memset

Comment: guess so, but i landed here trying to answer the same question but capable of running on an 8 bit microcontroller and non of the above compiled as i was missing some library or other, so i just wrote my own implementation that didn't need to call a library. Looking back now i prob could have used memmove and just wrote an implementation of strlen, but hay, it did what i needed it to do

Comment: well if you don't have strlen nor memset, poor you! That said, you should mention this in your answer because as is, it looks really complicated for no reason.

Comment: possibly personal opinion but i would say an answer that you can see what it will do line by line is far more use and less complicated than calling any function (standard or not) that your relying on some un-known non-visible code somewhere that someone else wrote to do what you need done. though i would probably accept that this approach may be less efficient